# Validate redux-form using react-validation-mixin

Tags: reactjs, validation, redux, redux-form, joi

I previously wrote a form using `Joi` and `react-validation-mixin` and it was working very well.

Now my team decided to migrate from the old platform and now we are using `redux` and `redux-form` for our new form.

What I would like to achieve is to keep my old validation system within `redux-form`.

So Basically the validation part was:

```
import Joi from 'joi';
import validation from 'react-validation-mixin';
import strategy from 'joi-validation-strategy';
import classnames from 'classnames';

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.validatorTypes = {
      screenName: Joi.string().label('Screen Name'),
      ...
    };

    this.getValidatorData = this.getValidatorData.bind(this);
    this.renderHelpText = this.renderHelpText.bind(this);
    this.getClasses = this.getClasses.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(field) {
    return (event) => {
      const { value } = event.target;
      this.props.updateField(field, value);
    };
  }

  getValidatorData() {
    return this.props;
  }

  getClasses(field) {
    const { isValid } = this.props;
    return classnames({
      'form-group': true,
      'has-error': !isValid(field),
    });
  }

  renderHelpText(message) {
    return (
      <span className="validation-error-message">{message}</span>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}

export default validation(strategy)(Form);
```

After we added `redux-form` our export changed to be:

```
export default connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.initialValues,
  }),
)(reduxForm({
  form: 'form',
})(Form));
```

I see `redux-form` accept a property called `validate` and in there I tried passing `validation(strategy)` but it just generate errors...

I also tried to chain the export including it but it doesn't work at all...

The question is, how can I validate my form using my old `react-validation-mixin` strategy with `Joi` while using `redux-form`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be an entirely easy fix, but you can minimize the impact of the refactor by using Joi as the basis for your validation. Since Joi validation is async you can use the [async validation from redux-forms](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/asyncchangevalidation/). That would look like this:

```
import Joi from 'joi';
import strategy from 'joi-validation-strategy';
...

class Form extends Component {
   ...
}

//ideally put this in a utility file so you can use it anywhere you have form validation
const asyncJoiValidationWrapper = (schema) => {
   return (reduxFormValues) => {
      strategy().validate(reduxFormValues, schema, {}, errors => {

         //joi validation errors should be in the error format redux-forms needs
         //i.e. {screenName: 'Screen Name is not valid'}
         throw errors;
      });
   }
}  

//take this out of your constructor
const validatorTypes = {
  screenName: Joi.string().label('Screen Name'),
  ...
};

export default connect(
   state => ({
      initialValues: state.initialValues,
}),
)(reduxForm({
   form: 'form',
   asyncValidate: asyncJoiValidationWrapper(validatorTypes)
})(Form));
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been away. I will test your approach asap. Thanks!